# Copy data from 2 different sheets and apply to another

Tags: vba, excel

I wish to copy data from 2 different sheets based on a cell value in the third sheet and put these values in the 3rd sheet after applying vlookup via vba...

I am using the following code to do so:

```
For TableRowCntr = 0 To i
        Range("A" & 9 + TableRowCntr + n).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = "Fiber No." & TableRowCntr + 1
        Selection.Font.Size = 8
        Range("A" & 11 + TableRowCntr + n).Select
        ActiveCell.Value = "Individual Splice Loss"
        Selection.Font.Size = 8
        With Selection.Font
            .ColorIndex = 4
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        FldrString = Null
        FIBERREPORTNAME = Null
        fiberreportname1 = Null
        Set appExcel = New Application
        Set appExcel1 = New Application
        'Set openWorkBook = ""
        'Set openWorkBook1 = ""
        For TableCOLCntr1 = 0 To j
            iTblCntr = Choose(TableCOLCntr1 + 1, "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", "AA", "AB", "AC")
            iAlphabet = iTblCntr & 9 + TableRowCntr + n
            Range(iAlphabet).Select
            FIBERREPORTNAME = Choose(TableRowCntr + 1, "A001", "A002", "A003", "A004", "A005", "A006", "A007", "A008", "A009", "A010", "A011", "A012", "A013", "A014", "A015", "A016", "A017", "A018", "A019", "A020", "A021", "A022", "A023", "A024", "A025", "A026", "A027", "A028", "A029", "A030", "A031", "A032", "A033", "A034", "A035", "A036", "A037", "A038", "A039", "A040", "A041", "A042", "A043", "A044", "A045", "A046", "A047", "A048", "A049", "A050", "A051", "A052", "A053", "A054", "A055", "A056")


            ' open workbook
            Set appExcel = New Application
            openWorkBookName = "C:\Users\Shikhar\Desktop\VTL Rewa\Ferozepur\Templates\Fiber Reports\Ferozepur to Jalallabad\A to B\" & SheetName & "\" & FIBERREPORTNAME
            Set openWorkBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Shikhar\Desktop\VTL Rewa\Ferozepur\Templates\Fiber Reports\Ferozepur to Jalallabad\A to B\" & SheetName & "\" & FIBERREPORTNAME)

            'C:\Users\Shikhar\Desktop\VTL Rewa\Ferozepur\Templates\Fiber Reports\Ferozepur to Jalallabad\A to B\



            ActiveCell.Value = "=vlookup(" & iTblCntr & "6," & FIBERREPORTNAME & ".xls!C17:E" & i + 17 & ",3,TRUE)"
            Selection.Font.Size = 8

            openWorkBook.Close
            appExcel.Quit
            Set appExcel1 = New Application
            fiberreportname1 = Choose(TableRowCntr + 1, "A001", "A002", "A003", "A004", "A005", "A006", "A007", "A008", "A009", "A010", "A011", "A012", "A013", "A014", "A015", "A016", "A017", "A018", "A019", "A020", "A021", "A022", "A023", "A024", "A025", "A026", "A027", "A028", "A029", "A030", "A031", "A032", "A033", "A034", "A035", "A036", "A037", "A038", "A039", "A040", "A041", "A042", "A043", "A044", "A045", "A046", "A047", "A048", "A049", "A050", "A051", "A052", "A053", "A054", "A055", "A056")
            openWorkBookName1 = "C:\Users\Shikhar\Desktop\VTL Rewa\Ferozepur\Templates\Fiber Reports\Ferozepur to Jalallabad\B to A\" & SheetName & "\" & fiberreportname1
            Set openWorkBook1 = appExcel1.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Shikhar\Desktop\VTL Rewa\Ferozepur\Templates\Fiber Reports\Ferozepur to Jalallabad\B to A\" & SheetName & "\" & fiberreportname1)

            iAlphabet = iTblCntr & 10 + TableRowCntr + n
            Range(iAlphabet).Select


            ActiveCell.Value = "=vlookup(" & iTblCntr & "6," & fiberreportname1 & ".xls!C17:E" & i + 17 & ",3,TRUE)"
            'ActiveCell.Value = "test 1"
            Selection.Font.Size = 8
            openWorkBook1.Close
            appExcel1.Quit
            iAlphabet = iTblCntr & 11 + TableRowCntr + n
            Range(iAlphabet).Select
            Selection.Font.Size = 8
            With Selection.Font
                .ColorIndex = 4
                .TintAndShade = 0
            End With
            ActiveCell.Value = "=sum(" & iTblCntr & 9 + TableRowCntr + n & ": " & iTblCntr & 10 + TableRowCntr + n & ")/2"
        Next
        n = n + 2
    Next
```

The problem i am facing is once the code is executed i get the same formula in both the cells... of Row 9 and 10.... whereas the objective is to have data from workbook 1 in row 9 and data from workbook 2 in row 10.

Kindly help.
Please do let me know if you need help in understanding the code above.

Comment: In general, this looks like it just needs a thorough debugging.  That is, add a breakpoint and step through the code until _you_ figure out what it is doing.  Once you know what it is doing, if you cannot answer **why** then update the question with the relevant information you gained while debugging.  When adding that info, please also reduce your code to the minimum necessary to produce the behavior you are seeing.  This process of thoroughly preparing the question generally helps people answer the question before they even ask it.  If not that, then it at least gives us a chance of helping.

Comment: I appreciate your response Byron, and will heed your advise. :)